# I want to concat a character before and after a word in bash

Tags: bash, substitution

I have declared a variable in a file like this:

```
export psw=text
```

And I would like to concat the `'` single character **before** and **after** the value of the variable. I mean, I want to replace the value for something like this:

```
 export psw='text'
```

How can I get that done?

I want to do it though a command. I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple and easy with Perl**

`perl -i -lpe 's/\=(\w+)$/='"'\\1'"'/' your-file`

`-i` save in-palce

**output**
`export psw='text'`

**how it works**
`s/.../` this part matches want you wnat
`/.../` this part is for **substitution** that part that you have matched already.
So in the first step you match `=(\w+)$`
and equal sign and a word and it should be end of the line. Okay after that you change this part to
`/='"'\\1'"'`
that means put an equal singe and a single quote that what that matched by **match group operator** `()` and then another single quote.
So it matches: `=text`
then substitute it with `='text'`

`-i` is for save the result 
`-p` is for printing to the screen + a while loop
`-l` put a new line
`-e`  a temporary program.

Just play with it **without `-i`** and then you little by little realize how it works.

---

**NOTE**
`'"'` is just for escape the single quote in bash.
`\\1` as well this one

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain the line for me? I am not familiarized with perl.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll wait :)

Comment: @Lost Please see and read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

This `sed` command will do your job:

```
sed -i.bak -E "s/(export[ \t]+[[:alnum:]]+=)([^']+)/\1'\2'/" file
```

The above expression would only add the single quotes when they are not there.

Comment: Could you explain the line to me?

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer the echo approach, you could also do it this way

```
pwd=text
export psw=$(echo "\'$pwd\'")
```

\ are needed to escape the single quotes so it'll be part of the string and you assign the output of echo of you variable with added quotes to itself

Comment: There is no reason to use `echo` here. Even if this is what the OP meant, `export psw="'$pwd'"` is entirely sufficient.

Comment: thx for the edit chepner, you were faster than me after i realized i forgot the code block